# how to assigning scriplet <%> value to a javascript variable ?

Tags: jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sBasePath = document.location.href.substring(0,document.location.href.lastIndexOf('_samples')) ;

var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( 'FCKeditor1' ) ;
oFCKeditor.BasePath = sBasePath ;
oFCKeditor.Height = 300 ;
//documents.write(test);
**oFCKeditor.Value = '';//i want to assign <%=strPageContent%> here but its not working....**

oFCKeditor.Create() ;//-->
</script>
```

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: im not getting the value of <%=strPageContent%>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a variable called `strPageContent`, then the following works:

```
oFCKeditor.Value = '<%=strPageContent%>';
```

If you have it as a request attribute (set with `request.setAttribute(..)` in a servlet for example), rather than as a variable, then:

```
oFCKeditor.Value = '${strPageContent}';
```

Comment: thank you Bozho (oFCKeditor.Value = '<%=strPageContent%>';) is working